# How can I optimize the following JavaScript which sets the CSS properties of Elements

Tags: javascript, css, performance

I have a page with JavaScript which takes a very long time to run. I have profiled the code using Firefox and following is the output.

[image]

As you can see I have moved the time consuming lines to a method `_doStuff`, which seems to do a lot of `Graphic` related things. Following is the content of the `_doStuff` method.

```
  _doStuff:function(tds,colHeaderTds,mainAreaTds ){
       for (i = 1; i < tds.length; i++) {
            if (colHeaderTds[i].offsetWidth <= tds[i].offsetWidth) {
              colHeaderTds[i].style.width = tds[i].offsetWidth + "px";
            }
            mainAreaTds[i].style.width = colHeaderTds[i].offsetWidth + "px";
          }

  },
```

I am assuming that the time consuming `Graphics` sections are due to setting the widths of the elements. Is this observation correct? And how should I go about optimizing the code so that it would take less time to load the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every iteration of your loop JS changes your DOM tree and forces browser to repaint it.

The good practice is to make a copy of your element, modify it in the loop, and after loop change the `.innerHTML` of the former element.

More reading about repaints on the topic [here](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/)